# Dynamic class to element with Less

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, bootswatch

I am using bootstrap.less and i want to add class="table table-striped table-hover" to all tables. Is it possible to achieve this?

I want to add something like:

```
table {
   //Add class here
}
```

Comment: without JS you cant.!

Comment: CSS/Less/Sass's job is to essentially paint styles onto the page. Adding classes dynamically would either be done with JS or in the templating layer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I believe you're looking for:

```
table {
  .table;
  .table-striped;
  .table-hover;

  /* Any other default table styles */
}
```

While you can't add `class="table table-striped table-hover"` to each element (that's more in the JS-realm), you can get the same effect by using the other classes as mixins added to the default `table` element's styles. See the [LESS documentation](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature) for more examples.