# How to add the class to input element from less

Tags: javascript, html, less

Hi i have to add the class "hide" to input element which having the class "display".

```
<input type="text" id="Text" class="display"/>
```

Is any ways to add the class to element from less?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic class to element with Less](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617789/dynamic-class-to-element-with-less)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.hide{
    background-color:blue;
 }
 .display{
   color:red;
   .hide;
 }
```

Comment: have you add hide class in your CSS like .hide{display:none;}

Comment: After adding the .hide class .This class have to add in input element like this
<input type="text" class="display hide"/>

Comment: Is it possible one?

Answer (score 0):

you can add

```
input .display {
  .hide{
   //css
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work..

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="display"/>
```

LESS

```
.hide {
  color: red;
}
input {
  &.display {
    .hide ();
  }
}
```